# Value in array cannot be updated VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, assign

I am trying to get the nth similar of a range compare to a text. The `Similarity` function is to return a percentage similarity between 2 texts.

```
Function SimilarText(ByVal CompareText As String, _
                    ByRef TargetCompare As Range, _
                    Optional ByVal RankSimilarity As Integer = 1) As Long

Dim compareResults() As Long
ReDim compareResults(RankSimilarity)
Dim simiResult As Single
Dim smallestIndex As Integer
Dim result As String
Debug.Print (CompareText)

For Each cell In TargetCompare
    simiResult = Similarity(cell.Value, CompareText)
    Debug.Print (simiResult)
    If simiResult > Application.Min(compareResults) Then
        smallestIndex = Application.Match(Application.Min(compareResults), compareResults, 0) - 1
        Debug.Print ("Index:" & smallestIndex)
        compareResults(smallestIndex) = CLng(simiResult)'//This doesnt seem to do anything. I tried without the conversion but still nothing.
        Debug.Print ("Smallest after update:" & compareResults(smallestIndex)) '//This always 0
    End If
Next cell

    SimilarText = Application.Min(compareResults) '//So this is also alway 0

End Function
```

I would expect the array element will be updated after each cell like '(0.22,0.44) but the result seems to always be 0.

Comment: Your array `compareResults()` is defined as Long, and that's only for integer numbers [Long data type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type). Have you tried changing the data type? Also, `CLng` forces a number to be long integer, not decimal.

Comment: I did not tried to change my data type. So that was the problem. Sorry for such a noob question.

Comment: Don't say sorry. **All of us** have been noobs in our life (and even some of us are noobs yet. There are amazing programmers here). It's It a mandatory stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array compareResults() is defined as `Long`, and that's only for integer numbers.

> **[Long data type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type)**

Change data type to something that admits decimal.

Also, in line `compareResults(smallestIndex) = CLng(simiResult)`, you are forcing a number to become a long integer. Use somethin else, or it will save a long integer number.